# How can I notify connection error to callers in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I am using `nodejs` for websocket connection(https://github.com/websockets/ws). I defines a `connect` method to return `Promise` to caller. This is the code:

```
connect = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        this.ws = new WebSocket(this.url, {});
        this.ws.on("open", () => {
          console.log("connected:", this.ws.readyState);
          resolve();
        });
        this.ws.on("close", function close() {
          console.log("disconnected");
          // how to throw error exception here?
        });

      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  };
```

the caller will call this method and try to reconnect if the connection failed.

```
connect().then(() => {
    ...
}).catch(() => {
    // do reconnect
})
```

it works fine if it fails to connect on the first time. But what if the connection drops. How can I let caller knows that there is an error happens?

One solution I can think of is to create an `event emitter` to notify caller that we need to reconnect. But if the code is used in many places in my project, I have to pass the `event emitter` to many places. Is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear for me which npm package you're using but if it's ws you can refer to this part of its README and adapt to your use case if necessary:
https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/README.md#how-to-detect-and-close-broken-connections